# Why not use images of configurations/logs/etc. when posting?

Tags: discussion, support

New Network Engineering users often use screenshots (images) for configurations, logs, etc.

- Why is using such images a problem?
- Isn't that why we have the option to upload images?
- What to do to show configurations so readers get a better
  understanding of the question?

---

<sub>(This question is based on [this Stack Overflow Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3745413)).</sub>

Comment: This should be a FAQ entry. (short answer: text is text, don't make it a 100 orders of magnitude larger image.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not post configurations, logs, error messages, debugs, or anything else that is represented in textual form as an image because:

- Images cannot be copied and pasted into an editor and tested/debugged.
- Images are large and hard to read on mobile devices, and often cost mobile users valuable data that is limited.
- Images are often blocked by corporate proxies, and therefore the configuration is not available to those readers. (This can also apply to some non-US countries that do not allow access to some sites, including image sites.)
- Images cannot be searched and therefore are not useful to future readers.
- Images are harder to read than text.
- For larger configurations, you may require multiple images one by one, which may break the continuation, readability & extensibility. However, a very large configuration text can easily be placed in a pre-formatted text format.
- Posting images of your configuration is more difficult than copying/pasting the actual configuration and formatting it.
- You're asking us to volunteer *our* time for free to solve *your* problem, and you should make it as easy as possible for us to do so.
- Images cannot be interpreted by screen readers, which is a major usability problem for those with visual impairments.
- Hosted image URLs often become stale and unavailable, breaking future ability to read the post.
- Images show a limited number of configuration lines. For moderately complex questions, you cannot fit all the required configuration on a single screen, even when you have created the most minimal example possible to reproduce the issue at hand.
- Others cannot improve your question by editing your image.
- Others cannot see if an error in your configuration is caused by invisible characters or misuse of Unicode characters that look the same.
- Images require more bandwidth than text: a simple 200 byte text snippet costs a thousand times less bandwidth than a 200 KB image.
- Some people are using the dark theme to browse the site. A white background in an image may hurt their eyes when browsing at late hours. Also, an image with a transparent background might be perfectly visible in the light theme but hardly visible in the dark theme!

---

**Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.**

---

Instead of using images, paste the *actual text* into your question, select it, and hit the Preformatted text button in the toolbar (it looks like `{}` and is next to the Image button) or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. (If you wish to format it by hand, you can insert four spaces before each line.)

Questions that contain images for text may be closed for lack of clarity and/or details. Once they are edited to include configurations, etc. in *plain text* form, they can be re-opened.

---

<sub>(This answer is based on [this Stack Overflow Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3745413).)</sub>